# How can we use Flag values in .if directive in Assembly

Tags: assembly, masm

I want to use flag values in my masm program as a condition.
For example:

```
.if eax > 0 &&  **sign flag is not set**
    continue
.else
    some code
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just wanted a signed comparison then take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26536227/3512216).

`.if eax > 0` performs a comparison which changes the flags. So you cannot check the sign *after* checking `EAX`. The order of the conditions is relevant. Here an example with MASM32:

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.CODE
main PROC
    mov eax, 1234
    mov edx, -1
    test edx, edx
    .if SIGN? && EAX > 0
        printf ("sign EAX=%d\n", eax)
    .else
        printf ("no match  EAX=%d  EDX=%d\n", eax, edx)
    .endif

    exit 0
main ENDP
END main
```

The `SIGN?` operator is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/36f4haza.aspx).

The other flag oriented operators are:

CARRY?
OVERFLOW?
PARITY?
ZERO?

A `NOT` is expressed as in C with [a prefixed exclamation mark](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/a3s92azz.aspx) (`!SIGN?`).